# How do I use PackageMaker to update an existing framework bundle?

Tags: macos, frameworks, packagemaker

I have developed a framework where I changed the library API. I changed the installed version letter to indicate the API change. However, the old versions are deleted by *Installer*.

How do I build a package that will leave the old API version beside the new library?

For example, *MyFramework* v1.0 implements version A of the interface and is installed at **/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/Versions/A**. v2.0 implements version B of the interface. It is installed in **/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/Versions/B**. The *Installer* applicaiton keeps deleting the directory **/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/A**. I want to keep that directory so that i have:

```
/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/A
/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/B
```